# How can I use T4 Custom Scaffolding over projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nuget, scaffolding, t4scaffolding

I'm using [T4Scaffolding](http://average-uffe.blogspot.com/2011/06/basics-in-t4scaffolding-in-visual.html) to do some do some C# code generation. Consider the following project structure:

[image: Project structure]
I've created a custrom scaffolder in the *Templates* project. Now I would like to run it for the *Dummy* project, but I get this exception:

[image]

How can I use Custom Scaffolding over projects?

The thing is: I've got 20 projects in TFS and I would like to manage the code of the t4 templates in 1 central location.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just be a matter of copying the files and Directories located in CodeTemplates/Scaffolders/BaseSuperModule into the Dummy Project and then calling the Scaffold command.

**Edit:** That makes perfect sense. I am in the middle of learning how to move custom t4Scaffolding code into a NuGet package. I think that would be the route that would work best for you. I will update my answer as soon as I figure it out.

**Edit 2:** I found this article and I went through it and have a working example. Give it a try and let me know if I might be able to help further.

http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/07/14/leverage-t4scaffolding-for-wcf-web-api.aspx

Comment: Well, I've got 20 projects in TFS and I would like to manage the code of the t4 templates in 1 central location. Copying the data to all the project wouldn't work.

Comment: I've read the Michelotti article and it shows how powerful T4 can be (that's why I love to learn some t4-fu!). Wrapping them in a package sounds like a cool idea, but I have (yet) no idea how to do something like that. Also, I can't publish this package on a public server. If I get a break-trough on it, I'll let you know. Let me know if you get any closer! :-)

Comment: I actually have a working prototype. I am just building on it as we speak. Do you have experience with creating Nuget packages? We currently have a Nuget server hosted in our Domain as I work for a bank. It was really easy to set up.

Comment: I've never created packages before. I'm now focusing on building the templates right and doing interaction with them, using pure T4Scaffolding (with some `cs.t4` files and a `ps1` file). After I'm done I hope I can find out how to package and distribute them.

Comment: Well let me know when you actually get to building your NuGet package :0)

Answer (score 1):

I think the trick is to do the scaffolding from the Templates project and pass in the name of the project you want to generate into e.g.

```
T4Scaffolding.Scaffolder(Description = "Creates a model entity")][CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)][string]$EntityName,
    [string]$ProjectName,
    [string]$CodeLanguage,
    [string[]]$TemplateFolders,
    [switch]$Force = $false
)

# Find the code project, or abort
$project = Get-Project ( $ProjectName) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (!$project) { throw "Cannot find code project corresponding to solution '$ProjectName'" }

$entityFile = $EntityName
Add-ProjectItemViaTemplate $entityFile -Template EntityTemplate `
    -Model @{ Namespace = $namespace; EntityName = $EntityName; MappingName = $MappingName } `
    -SuccessMessage "Added Model non-gen output at {0}" `
    -TemplateFolders $TemplateFolders -Project $ProjectName -CodeLanguage $CodeLanguage -Force:$false
```

You must pass a string to the -Project argument in Add-ProjectItemViaTemplates not a project object

If you already know the projects that the various scaffolders need to apply to, then you can set a default value for ProjectName in the scaffolder.

There's some examples of this in the MvcScaffolding package.